Videos Not Loading in Telegram WebView: Triggering JavaScript Execution on Page Load
Good evening, everyone.
I came across the need to place around 10 video files on a website (to showcase app functionality), with a total size of about 10 MB. The website itself is quite fast.
However, there’s a problem: when accessing the website through a link in Telegram, only the first video loads, while the others do not (it opens in the WebView, of course). The remaining videos only start loading if I interact with the page (tapping multiple times on the screen or scrolling through a slider).
Has anyone encountered a way to trigger JavaScript execution immediately after the page loads?
I've tried various methods like listening for scroll events, touch interactions, etc., but none of them seem to work.

IntersectionObserver: Attempted to preload and play videos as they approach the viewport, adjusting rootMargin and threshold.

Event-Based Triggers: Implemented scroll, touchstart, and pointerdown events to manually trigger video loading or simulate interaction.

Forced Interaction Simulation: Tried forcing synthetic user interactions using JavaScript to "wake up" the WebView’s JavaScript engine.

Immediate JS Execution: Added basic scripts to force activity on page load, such as toggling classes or logging events.

Different Video Attributes: Experimented with data-src, preload, autoplay, and other video attributes for lazy loading and manual play.


Unfortunately, none of these reliably resolved the issue in the Telegram WebView.
The video loading now works through the following script:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const lazyVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-load');
  const pauseVideo = (video) => {
    if (!video.paused) {
      video.pause();
    }
  };
  const playVideo = (video) => {
    if (video.paused) {
      video.play().catch((err) => {
        console.warn(`Ошибка воспроизведения видео: ${err}`);
      });
    }
  };
  const preloadVideo = (video) => {
    const source = video.querySelector('source');
    if (source && source.dataset.src) {
      source.src = source.dataset.src;
      video.load();
      source.removeAttribute('data-src');
    }
  };
  const observerOptions = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: '0px 0px 500px 0px'
  };
  const lazyObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const video = entry.target;

      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        preloadVideo(video);
        playVideo(video);
      } else {
        pauseVideo(video);
      }
    });
  }, observerOptions);
  lazyVideos.forEach((video) => lazyObserver.observe(video));
});

The video is inserted with the parameters:
video(loop muted loading="lazy" playsinline preload="none" controls poster="/images/wallet/video/poster-slider-2.png")

And yes, I solved the issue by setting a poster and enabling controls for all videos. I then remove the controls via JS for devices that successfully execute the code. Overall, this even helped revive Telegram, and now it almost always loads the videos correctly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The code has been added, and overall, the issue has also been resolved.
